# Can I scrape metrics from AWS ECS Fargate by using node-exporter docker image as sidecar with my microservice?

Tags: prometheus, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using AWS ECS Fargate for my applications,I want to scrape metrics like cpu and memory using prometheus node-exporter as sidecar, is it possible?

I have tried it, I am getting metrics too but I am suspecting those metrics are of node-exporter container itself not the micro-service.

Answer (score 0):

A sidecar in a Fargate task would run as a non-privileged container on an infrastructure (i.e. host/OS) that is completely shielded from the user. I don't know the details of how the `node-exporter` works but I assume it assumes a level of access to the host that you can't achieve in a Fargate task. I'd be curious to see the metrics you are getting by doing so because my first gut would have been "you'll be getting nothing".

An application running in a Fargate task can introspect itself and extract performance stats for both the task as a whole and the container running within it. This is accomplished by querying the [ECS Task metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html). I suspect what would need to be done is .. creating a special purpose sidecar that grab these stats and expose them as a `/metrics` endpoint of the task. I am not aware anything like this exist but I chatted internally about this (I am part of the AWS container team) and this may stimulate some of us to sketch something and post it as an experiment/example (no promise here though).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mreferre. Fargate will not allow host/OS level inspection.

That being said, the following project queries the ECS task metadata endpoint and exposes results on `/metrics`.

https://github.com/Spaced-Out/ecs-container-exporter/tree/2.2.0

The task definition would look something similar to the following:

```
{
    ...
    "dockerLabels": {
      "PROMETHEUS_EXPORTER_PATH": "/metrics",
      "PROMETHEUS_EXPORTER_PORT": "9545"
    },
    "image": "raags/ecs-container-exporter:2.2.0",
    "name": "foo-svc-ecs-container-exporter",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 9545
      }
    ]
    ...
}
```

Note, `dockerLabels` above is from use of the [prometheus-ecs-discovery](https://github.com/teralytics/prometheus-ecs-discovery) project.